# How would I .show( ) a div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

Lets say I had a website full of pictures posted vertically. As a scroll down, I want to use javascript/jquery to load in their description (and have the previous description hide). How would I go about doing this?

Please let me know. Thanks.

An example would be this page here.
https://stackoverflow.com/about

As you scroll, many jquery events take place.

Comment: sounds like a lazy load..

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: using zeniths idea but doing a bit more working out to find the scroll pos to then control when you want to display items

Comment: Yeah, it's actually not crazy, because this site... http://stackoverflow.com/about , does it. When you scroll, certain jquery events take place.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like [scroll to](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) etc that you can then find the co-ordinates / location and then perform the script you require etc

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like the jquery [appear plugin](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)
It fires when the element comes into view.

Could do it manually as well, when scrolling, check all the container elements holding your hidden description to see if they fall within the viewable browser and show their description elements if so.